# slow ffmpeg's images per second when creating video from images

Tags: ffmpeg, screenshot

I have a series of screenshots from a demo that I want to put in a video. I am using ffmpeg for this purpose. The command is `ffmpeg -f image2 -i screenshot_%5d.png -vcodec mpeg4 demo.avi`. However, the video length is shorter than what I want, and it moves very fast. How do I specify how many images per second I want? I tried the `-r` argument but that did not work.

Comment: Can you show where you put the -r option? The rate can apply both to the input rate and output rate. See examples at: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Description

Comment: @RogerLindsjö : Thanks for pointing that out. I was specifying the -r just before the output. Trying it before the input file worked. Please go ahead and post an answer if you wish, otherwise I will do it after some time.

Answer (score 14):

You can change video speed by adjusting the “presentation time stamp” (PTS).
In your case:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i screenshot_%5d.png -vcodec mpeg4  -vf "setpts=5*PTS" demo.avi
```

You'll get video, which plays 5 times slower, than normal video.

If you want to make it 5 times faster:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i screenshot_%5d.png -vcodec mpeg4  -vf "setpts=(1/5)*PTS" demo.avi
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the capture rate

```
 # Note: The frame rate (-r) can be an integer or a float 

 ffmpeg  -r 23.976 \
         -f image2 \
         -i test-%06d.png \
         -vcodec mpeg4 \
         test.avi
```