# Make video from images with ffmpeg/imagemagic

Tags: image, image-processing, video, ffmpeg, imagemagick

I want to convert jpg images to mp4 video without resizing image(keep original images size and well formated video)

I have tried lot's of solutions of `ffmpeg` and `imagemagic` (links given below)but both crop images after converting in video format and i want a video from images with original image size.

Solution will be appreciated with `ffmpeg` or `imagemagick`. :)

[slow ffmpeg's images per second when creating video from images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241433/slow-ffmpegs-images-per-second-when-creating-video-from-images)

[image to video ffmpegf](https://www.tecmint.com/ffmpeg-commands-for-video-audio-and-image-conversion-in-linux/)

[FFMPEG An Intermediate Guide/image sequence](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence)

[How can I create a video file from a set of jpg images? [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610903/how-can-i-create-a-video-file-from-a-set-of-jpg-images)

[How to create a video from images with FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg)

[FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

[Make video from still image sequence](https://leonawicz.github.io/mapmate/reference/ffmpeg.html)

[Combining images with ImageMagick](http://gotofritz.net/blog/geekery/combining-images-imagemagick/)

[Imagemagick.org](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#jpg_read)

[image]

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i na%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

[image]
on large image(1600X1200) its execute successfully but not generate a smooth video.

on small image(300x168) its show error. i also try this command on small image

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i abc%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4 -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2"
```

Comment: Show your `ffmpeg` command and the complete console output.

Comment: i used this command of ffmpeg 
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i image-%05d.jpg -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4

Comment: please see the console output in thread

Comment: These two commands making videos with correct delay time but with different resolution pics in video it convert all the image to first image resolution. it should keep original size all image in video
`ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1/5 -i na%03d.jpg -y -r 25 test.mp4`
`ffmpeg -y -r 1/5 -i na%03d.jpg -r 25 out.mp4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this work for me i use this in loop

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i na002.jpg -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -strict 1  -shortest -vf "scale='min(1280,iw)':min'(720,ih)':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" test.mp4

ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -vf "scale='min(1280,iw)':min'(720,ih)':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" out1.media


ffmpeg -i "C:\xampp\htdocs\social_media\public\uploads\stories\temp_media\81/temp0.mp4" -i "C:\xampp\htdocs\social_media\public\uploads\stories\temp_media\81/temp1.mp4" -i "C:\xampp\htdocs\social_media\public\uploads\stories\temp_media\81/temp2.mp4" -i "C:\xampp\htdocs\social_media\public\uploads\stories\temp_media\81/temp3.mp4" -filter_complex "[0]setdar=16/9[a];[1]setdar=16/9[b];[2]setdar=16/9[c];[3]setdar=16/9[d];[a][0:a][b][1:a][c][2:a][d][3:a] concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]"
```